# How to set keep alive in weblogic using WLST?

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

I have requirement to automate the server deployment process; I have found a way to do it using WLST. However I am stuck at one point.
I need to set some configurations in weblogic,

for e.g.
`cmo.setGracefulShutdownTimeout(300)`
`cmo.setIgnoreSessionsDuringShutdown(true)`**

But I could not find method to enable Keep Alive for HTTP protocol in weblogic server.

I have tried below combinations but that did not work:

`cmo.setKeepAliveEnable(true)

 cmo.setKeep-Alive(true)

 cmo.setKeepAlive(true)`

Kindly tell me how to enable keep alive property of HTTP protocol in weblogic using WLST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you find these properties or do you get an error message when you try to set values ?

Comment: I cant find this attribute with edit() tree command and also i am getting this error "AttributeError: setKeepAliveEnabled" while setting the value

Comment: The mbean is serverConfig:/Servers/<ServerName>/WebServer/<ServerName>

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Keep alive was in different directory . Thanks for the help